# azure HDInsight script action

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to copy a file from a accessible data lake to blob storage  while spinning up the cluster.

I am using this command from Azure documentation

hadoop distcp adl://data_lake_store_account.azuredatalakestore.net:443/myfolder wasb://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/example/data/gutenberg

Now, If I am trying to automate this instead of hardcoding, how do I use this in script action. To be specific how can I dynamically get the the container name and storage_account_name associated while spinning up the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

First as below,

> A Script Action is simply a Bash script that you provide a URI to, and parameters for. The script runs on nodes in the HDInsight cluster.

So you just need to refer to the offical tutorial [`Script action development with HDInsight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-script-actions-linux) to write your script action and know how to run it. Or you can call the REST API [`Run Script Actions on a running cluster (Linux cluster only)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#run-script-actions-on-a-running-cluster-linux-cluster-only) to run it automatically.

For how to dynamically get the container name & storage account, a way for any language is to call the REST API [`Get configurations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#get-configurations) and extract the property of you want from the `core-site` in the JSON response, or just to call [`Get configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#get-configuration) REST API with parameter `core-site` as `{configuration Type}` in the url and extract the property of you want from the JSON response.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Here is what I am trying. I have created a cluster using the portal. Now when I am uploading a shell file to run on the head node, the script action is failing.  The objective of the script is to download a tar file from data lake. So I wanted to test it out and wrote a single line shell file (mkdir test) , even this script is failing. Anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: @kmk1 I think you were talking about this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142391/script-action-to-install-spark-job-server-on-hdinsight-head-node. It seems to be yours.